# Android - Throwing fatal exception where it wasn't before

Tags: android, progress-bar, classcastexception

Explanation at the end of the code

Java:

```
void GetNextQuestion()
{
    QuestNum++;
    /// ERROR ON VERY NEXT LINE
    ProgressBar pbar = (ProgressBar)this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    TextView tvSection = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.section);
    TextView tvSubsection = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.subsection);
    TextView tvQuest = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.quest);
    if(QuestNum > 0 && QuestNum < 180)
    {
        tvSection.setText(R.string.s1);
        tvSubsection.setText(R.string.ss1);
        spin.setSecondaryProgress((int)((QuestNum/180) * 1000));
    }
    if(QuestNum > 179 && QuestNum < 285)
    {
        tvSection.setText(R.string.s2);
        tvSubsection.setText(R.string.ss2);         
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1">



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="57dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:src="@drawable/devil" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:text="@string/nunca"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:visibility="invisible" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subsection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
    android:text="@string/nunca"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/helpico" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/subsection"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/exitico" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/haveyou"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/subsection"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/nunca"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/load"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butyes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="Yes" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/butno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="No" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:max="1000"
        android:progress="0"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<com.google.ads.AdView
   android:id="@+id/adView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:adSize="BANNER"
   app:adUnitId="a14ffb06b21e68e"
   app:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(20649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(20649): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
at com.ndai.ptest.a1000test.GetNextQuestion(a1000test.java:146)
at com.ndai.ptest.a1000test$QuestAnsTask.onPostExecute(a1000test.java:3319)
at com.ndai.ptest.a1000test$QuestAnsTask.onPostExecute(a1000test.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is what i don't understand...it is giving me a casting error...i am casting a progressbar tp a progressbar...am i just missing a typo or something...i just need an extra set of eyes on this one

EDIT:

I did however not receive this error until after i rearranged stuff on the xml

Comment: I think i may have just found the answer...give me a min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I FIXED IT

I was reading how other people have been having the same issues when not using the GUI to change the layout...so i followed these steps

1. Fix the project (right click project, got android tools then the only option that says fix)
2. Delete R.java
3. Fix The Project again

Answer (score 2):

What was happening is that eclipse (Or what ever you use) didn't want to update R file with the right data, meaning that the id of your progress bar or what ever it was casting was being mixed up with one of the buttons, nice little bug for ya.